# How to run a program as Adminstrator through Python

Tags: python, admin

I'm currently working on getting rid of a virus from my computer, but I need admin rights to do so. I tried to make myself admin by going to the Command Line, and typing:

net localgroup administrators johan /add

But seeing, as I myself don't have admin, I get hit with:

System Error 5

So I decided to attempt to run Command Prompt as an administrator through python, but am running into this problem. Here's my code so far.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avu7i.png)

Doing this, I get an error saying:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6XGJ.png)

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you cant become admin if you are not admin.

Comment: You *really* shouldn't be trying to delete a virus that is currently running. Besides, you can never be sure you got rid of it fully. Have a look at [this post over at security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/138617/197514) for some better options on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

why cant you just go to lusrmgr.msc and change any configuration there?